# Dynamically alter contents of a div and append to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically I have this div in body

```html
<body>
  <div id="main_content"></div>
</body>
```

Now I am downloading some data from the internet (a set of boolean data) and I have this div template. Let's say the data is (true, false, true). Then for each data I want to alter the template div. For example: first one is true so inside the template div I will change the **sub1 div's** height to 40 px; if it's false, I'd change **sub2 div's** height to 40 px; and then I'd append this modified template div to **main_content div**

**Template div:**

```css
.child{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
}

.sub1{
  width:300px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#0FF;
}

.sub2{
  width:300px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#F0F;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
  <div class="sub1"></div>
  <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

After all this this should be the final output of **main_content div**

[image]

What would be the easiest way of doing this using **HTML/CSS/JS**.

Thanks

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D What makes you think I haven't tried it. And this is just an simple example of what I want to accomplish. The only reason I've asked this question is because I've been stuck and researching for past 5 days and still haven't found the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/RPXBey)

Long answer:
I would use js to dynamically generate your template div:

```
function makeTemplateDiv() {
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.className = "child"
  var sub1 = document.createElement('div');
  sub1.className = "sub1"
  var sub2 = document.createElement('div');
  sub2.className = "sub2"
  child.appendChild(sub1);
  child.appendChild(sub2);
  return child;
}
```

Then make a css class for a taller 40 px

```
.taller {
  height: 40px;
}
```

Then use js to to alter your template based on a passed in value

```
function alterTemplateDiv(value) {
  var template = makeTemplateDiv();
  if(value) {
    template.getElementsByClassName("sub1")[0].className += " taller";
  } else {
    template.getElementsByClassName("sub2")[0].className += " taller";
  }
  return template;
}
```

Then use js to pass in your array of values, make the divs, and append them

```
function appendDivs(arrayOfValues) {
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main_content");
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
    mainDiv.appendChild(alterTemplateDiv(arrayOfValues[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: @iitumstudant It is generally recommended to keep HTML as an actual template (I.e. not contained in JavaScript). Everything outside of the makeTemplateDiv() function is perfectly fine here, though.

Comment: @BDawg : You are right. Instead of creating template inside JS, I've created it in HTML doc and hid it and using that as an template. I was having trouble figuring out how to alter div contents using JS which was answered in alterTemplateDiv() function :)

Comment: @iitumstudant If you have an actual div instead of a script like I did in my answer, just be careful. Even if it's hidden, if it contains anything that creates an HTTP request (images, audio, and iframes in particular), you may find that it slows down the loading of your page considerably. I once did this on a site with multiple embedded YouTube and SoundCloud iframes and it was SUPER slow until I learned my lesson and changed it over.

Comment: @BDawg Hi, thanks for the heads up. The template div is just a structure. All the data ie images etc are added in JS and then appended to the page. The template div does not have anything

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question begs for a million different types of answers, but I think this generally keeps with most best practices for front end coding without the use of a framework:

```js
// Self-invoking function for scoping
// and to protect important global variables from other script changes
// (The variable references can be overwritten)
(function (window, document) {
 
    var templateText,
        generatedEl,
        topEl,
        bitArray;

    // Data
    bitArray = [true, false, true];

    // Get template text
    templateText = document.getElementById('my-template').text.trim();

    // Loop through your T / F array
    for (var i = 0, l = bitArray.length; i < l; i++) {

        // Create a DIV and generate HTML within it
        generatedEl = document.createElement('div');
        generatedEl.innerHTML = templateText;

        // Modify the new HTML content
        topEl = generatedEl.getElementsByClassName('child')[0];
        topEl.className += bitArray[i] ? ' typeA' : ' typeB' ;

        // Insert generated HTML (assumes only one top-level element exists)
        document.getElementById('my-container').appendChild(generatedEl.childNodes[0]);    
    }

})(window, document);
```

```css
.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

/* For true */
.child.typeA > .sub1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #0FF;
}

.child.typeA > .sub2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #F0F;
}

/* For false */
.child.typeB > .sub1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #0FF;
}

.child.typeB > .sub2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div id="my-container">
    
    <!-- HTML Template -->
    <script id="my-template" type="text/template">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="sub1"></div>
            <div class="sub2"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
    
</div>
```

Note that the HTML content, JavaScript code and CSS are all kept very separated. This is based on the concepts of "Separation of Concerns" and "Unobtrusive JavaScript". I invite you to read up on them if you haven't already. Also, front end templating can be used for dynamic content like I did here, but I would recommend doing templating on the back end when you can. It works better for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes it easier to manipulate the DOM, so here is [another solution](https://jsfiddle.net/yo4k0t3h/) for your problem:

```
var data = [true, false, true];

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

    var height1;
    var height2;
    if (data[i] == true) {
        height1 = 40;
        height2 = 20;
    }
    else {
        height1 = 20;
        height2 = 40;
    }

    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    $(div1).toggleClass("sub1")
        .height(height1)
        .appendTo("#main_content");

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    $(div2).toggleClass("sub2")
        .height(height2)
        .appendTo("#main_content");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for such quick response. This works but this question is just an small example of what I want to accomplish. In my code the template dive will have a lot of childs (20-30) divs inside and depending on the data I will need to alter the template div and then append it. So instead of of appending the sub1, sub2 divs directly, I need to first construct the template div with appropriate sub1, sub2 div and then append the template div to main_content